# In Pyside, how can I handle close call when clicking a close button?

Tags: pyside

What I have to handle a close doesn't seem to work. The error I get when running this is:

> Error: AttributeError: file  line 82: 'Ui_Dialog' object has no attribute 'close'

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui, QtUiTools
import maya.cmds as cmds

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
        Dialog.resize(400, 300)
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 20, 131, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))

        ............
        ................
        ..................
        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

        self.swapRefBtn.clicked.connect(self.swapRefBtn_clicked)
        self.closeBtn.clicked.connect(self.close())       <---- THIS HERE WON'T WORK        

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        ............
        ................
        ..................


    def swapRefBtn_clicked(self):
       pass                 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication.instance()
    if app is None:
        app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)       
    Dialog = QtGui.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with using ui files, but I think `UI_Dialog` is suppose to have an `__init__` function where you can call `QDialog constructor`. Check the type of `self`: if it's an object, it doesn't have a close method. And if it's a `QDialog`, there are more appropriate functions than `close`, just read the doc.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to connect the close button to **QDialog.accept** or **QDialog.reject** slot.

As for how to handle them:

**Example**

```
import sys
import PyQt4.QtGui as qg

class Dialog(qg.QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setup_widgets()

    def setup_widgets(self):
        self.ok = qg.QPushButton('OK')
        self.ok.clicked.connect(self.accept)

        self.cancel = qg.QPushButton('Cancel')
        self.cancel.clicked.connect(self.reject)

        layout = qg.QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.ok)
        layout.addWidget(self.cancel)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def accept(self):
        # Your logic here
        super().accept()

    def reject(self):
        response = qg.QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Warning', 'Cancel?',
                                          qg.QMessageBox.Yes | qg.QMessageBox.No)
        if response == qg.QMessageBox.Yes:
            super().reject()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qg.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = Dialog()
    dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

See also: **QDialog.done()**